# How to sort posts by 1-5 star rating selected by the user in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, sorting, posts, rating

How to get than after a user clicks 5 stars I get that info and use it to sort posts who have a 5 star rating.

```
<form action="">
<img class="ylli-1" src="img/icons8-christmas-star.svg" alt="">
    <img class="ylli-2" src="img/icons8-christmas-star.svg" alt="">
    <img class="ylli-3" src="img/icons8-christmas-star.svg" alt="">
    <img class="ylli-4" src="img/icons8-christmas-star.svg" alt="">
    <img class="ylli-5" src="img/icons8-christmas-star.svg" alt="">
</form>
```

Comment: Your question fall into task, you need to ask any developer to write any program for you or you have to read through informative threads available on stackoverflow like https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/267882/how-to-order-top-rated-results-by-date-and-meta-key

There is many more you need to be a little more precise what really you want to achieve with rating.

Comment: @AdeelAbbas thanks for the answer.What I want to achieve is when a user selects to be shown posts that have i.e a 5 star review,query that and display posts who are 5 stars.Hope I was clear!